# Working with non recursive lists

Tags: list, f#

So I've been working with lists recently.
I want to make a non recursive function `name: int list -> int`, that returns the difference between the highest and lowest number in a list.
Is there a simple way of doing it with maybe `list.fold, list.filter or list.exist?`

I guess i can do it with `list.max` and `list.min`, but i want to try with some other functions.

Any help?

Comment: `List.fold`: yes of course - `List.filter` AFAIK no - `List.Exist` ... well(?) ... can you put it in words what you want/have to do? Hint: you can translate every loop into a `fold` rather mechanically....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To you mean something like this?

```
let distanceMinMax xs = 
    let (min,max) = List.fold (fun (min, max) x -> ((if x < min then x else min), (if x > max then x else max))) 
                              (System.Int32.MaxValue, System.Int32.MinValue)
                              xs
    (max - min)
```

Tested in the REPL:

```
> distanceMinMax [1;-1;2;5;7;-3];;
val it : int = 10
```

Hint: The empty list [] is not supported:

```
> distanceMinMax [];;
val it : int = 1
```

Comment: You could handle the empty list case using option ; returning None and Some distance otherwise (as an aside you put max instead of min inside the first if - I can't edit because it's too few characters)

Comment: Nice hint @Sehnsucht! I have just corrected the function.